# Find the directional derivative in the direction of a parametric vector

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

> Find the directional derivative at $(1,0,0)$ of the function $$f(x,y,z) = x^2 + ye^z)$$ in the direction of the tangent vector at $g(0)$ to the curve $\mathbb{R}^3$ defined parametrically by $$g(t) = (3t^2 + t + 1, 2t , t^2)$$

$$\begin{align}
\nabla f(x,y,z) &= (2x, e^z, ye^z) \\
\frac{\partial f}{\partial g}(1,0,0) &= (2x, e^z, ye^z) \cdot (et^2 + t + 1, 2t, t^2) \\
&= 6t^2 + 2t + 2 + 2t \\
&= 6t^2 + 4t + 2
\end{align}$$

My textbook says that the answer is $2\sqrt{5}$, which I don't think makes any sense and I think the book is wrong, but would like some other input on the matter, thank you

Comment: You multiplied by $g(t)$, instead of the (normalized) tangent vector to $g$ at $t=0$. Compute $g'(t)=(6t+1,2,2t)$. So, $g'(0)=(1,2,0)$. Normilized it is $\frac{1}{\|g'(0)\|}g'(0)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}(1,2,0)$.

Comment: got it, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

We have

$$g'(t) = (6t + 1, 2 , 2t) \implies g'(0)=(1,2,0)\implies \vec t=\frac1{\sqrt 5}(1,2,0)$$

then

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial g}(1,0,0) =\nabla f(1,0,0)\cdot \vec t= \frac1{\sqrt 5}(2,1,0)\cdot(1,2,0)=\frac4{\sqrt 5}=\frac45 \sqrt 5 $$